# JBilling creating custom fields

Tags: java, tomcat, billing, jbilling

I am very new to jbilling and i  am trying to create new custom fields under `Add Customer` and in `Add Product` page.

I need `Blood Group` in Add Customer and `Expiry Date` in Add Products.

So how can i add these custom fields?
Do i need to add it using code or is there some other way of doing it.

Also if i create these fields do the SOAP inter face for these fields gets created also? To access it from Jbilling Client API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom fields on the fly in JBilling. No programming required.

Please confirm your jBilling version. If it is 3.1 or higher, you will see a 'Meta Fields' link under 'Configuration' main menu in the jBilling GUI. On the Meta Fields configuration page, you may select an Entity first (CUSTOMER, PRODUCT in your case) and add/edit meta fields. You can also configure Data Types, default values, mandatory flag as well.

Answer (score 0):

U can also use api for creating meta fields. jbilling provide apis for creating meta fields

**api.createMetaField(MetaFieldWS metafieldWs)**

you can find above method in WebServicesSessionSpringBean.java

**public Integer createMetaField(MetaFieldWS metafieldWs)**

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
    createMetaField()
}
public static void createMetaField() {

        try {

            JbillingAPI api = JbillingAPIFactory.getAPI();

            MetaFieldWS metafield = new MetaFieldWS();
            metafield.setEntityType(EntityType.CUSTOMER);
            metafield.setName("BloodGroup");
            metafield.setDataType(DataType.STRING);
            metafield.setPrimary(true);
            metafield.setMandatory(false);          
            metafield.setEntityId(api.getCompany().getId());

            Integer result = api.createMetaField(metafield);
            System.out.println("Metafield Created field ID:" + result);
        } catch (JbillingAPIException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```